# How to Debug a node.js AWS-SAM Lambda function written in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, vscode-debugger, aws-sam

With an AWS-SAM project written with Typescript handlers is it possible to debug locally with configuration from the launch.json file? Any handler in a js file works correctly but ts files are ignored when you try to debug them. You end up with an error that the module is not found.

*ERROR  Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module*

Here is the launch.json

```
{
     "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "aws-sam",
        "request": "direct-invoke",
        "name": "blocksGet",
        "invokeTarget": {
            "target": "code",
            "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/lambda/blocks/",
            "lambdaHandler": "blocksjs.handler"
        },
        "lambda": {
            "runtime": "nodejs14.x",
            "payload": {},
            "environmentVariables": {}
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: What is your `launch.json` configuration?  See [Configuration options for debugging serverless applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/serverless-apps-run-debug-config-ref.html) in the AWS docs.

Comment: this is the launch.json: {
     "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "aws-sam",
        "request": "direct-invoke",
        "name": "blocksGet",
        "invokeTarget": {
            "target": "code",
            "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/lambda/blocks/",
            "lambdaHandler": "blocksjs.handler"
        },
        "lambda": {
            "runtime": "nodejs14.x",
            "payload": {},
            "environmentVariables": {}
        }
    }]
}

Comment: This does not work...

Answer (score 0):

The debugger [will respect breakpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/serverless-apps-troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-typescript-debugging) in the `.ts` Lambda handler file if inline source maps are enabled in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"inlineSourceMap": true,
```

Comment: Yes, that's in the documentation, it must be some error in my project that causes it to fail.

Comment: @stuart were you able to figure this out. I have the same issue and changing inlineSourceMap to true in the tsconfig has not helped.